# Formatting Hierarchical Structure from Database rows with PHP

Tags: php, structure, hierarchy

I'm tearing my hair out trying to format a hierarchical layout from database rows such as these with PHP. Can anybody help me, I've tried using a foreach loop and setting a switch if the country is different but I couldn't get the others to format correctly.

```
ID      City        State         Country
==================================================
1       Dallas      Texas         United States
2       Baltimore   Maryland      United States
3       Houston     Texas         United States
4       Essex       London        United Kingdom
5       Salford     Manchester    United Kingdom
```

Giving me the following (preferably in a multi-select field)

```
United States
--Maryland
----Baltimore
--Texas
----Dallas
----Houston
United Kingdom
-- London
---- Essex
-- Manchester
----Salford


<select multiple="yes" name="locations">
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="Maryland">-- Maryland</option>
  <option value="Baltimore">---- Baltimore</option>
  <option value="Texas">-- Texas</option>
  <option value="Dallas">---- Dallas</option>
  <option value="Houston">---- Houston</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="London">-- London</option>
  <option value="Essex">---- Essex</option>
  <option value="Manchester">-- Manchester</option>
  <option value="Salford">---- Salford</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do here.

Comment: I disagree.  I think it's clear what you want, what's unclear is the methodology you've tried.  You should generally post code samples to explain your thought process.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan That's a good point. Noted for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic goal here is to iterate over the rows, placing them in the hierarchical structure you're looking for.  I suggest something like this:  (This will probably net you some E-STRICT Warnings, but a little error checking here and there never killed anyone).  You can then print from a hierarchical structure at will.

```
$locations = array();
foreach($rows as $row)
    locations[$row->Country][$row->state][$row->city] = $row->id;

echo '<select multiple="yes" name="locations">';

$foreach($locations as $country=>$states){
    echo "<option value='$country'>$country</option>";
    $foreach($states as $state=>$cities){
        echo "<option value='$state'>-- $state</option>";
        $foreach($cities as $city=>$id)
            echo "<option value='$city'>---- $city</option>";
    }
}

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I tried your code but only one city ever gets displayed? :( Seems like it's overwriting the city each time.

Comment: Sorry.  Had to change it to use the index as the city.

Comment: That'll do Frankie, that'll do. Thanks :)